# Change executable file name via prctl() in Linux

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I need to change name of executable file in Linux. Name of executable file is passed via `argv[0]`. It can be checked in `/proc/pid/cmdline` file that consists of name of executable and its arguments. I tried to use `prctl()` function with `PR_SET_MM` arguments and file descriptor of another executable file hider.out.

```
int prctl_routine(char* name)
{
    errno = 0;
    int fd = open(name, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int ret = prctl(PR_SET_MM, PR_SET_MM_EXE_FILE, fd, 0, 0);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("prctl");
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...
    // show pid to find the right process
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    std::cout << "pid = " << pid << std::endl;

    prctl_routine(argv[1]);
    sleep(1000);
    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Running this program like this `./a.out hider.out` and performing `cat /proc/pid/cmdline` I've got the following error:

`prctl: Operation is not permitted`

Question 0: Am I right executing `open()` function with `O_RDONLY` flag?

Question 1: man prctl tells:
"To change the symbolic link, one needs to unmap all existing executable memory areas, including those created by the kernel itself".

How could it be done?

Comment: Aren't you just looking for `setproctitle`?

Comment: @zwol I don't want to change the title of the process. I just want to hide executable file name from `/proc/pid/cmdline` or replace it with another one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if PR_SET_NAME does not answer your question, I can suggest what is done in the source code of [LXC](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/initutils.c) with PR_SET_MM. I copied their function here and arranged it to make it work outside of LXC:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <syscall.h>




/*
 * Sets the process title to the specified title. Note that this may fail if
 * the kernel doesn't support PR_SET_MM_MAP (kernels <3.18).
 */
int setproctitle(char *title)
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    int i, fd, len;
    char *buf_ptr, *tmp_proctitle;
    char buf[4096];
    int ret = 0;
    ssize_t bytes_read = 0;
    static char *proctitle = NULL;

    /*
     * We don't really need to know all of this stuff, but unfortunately
     * PR_SET_MM_MAP requires us to set it all at once, so we have to
     * figure it out anyway.
     */
    unsigned long start_data, end_data, start_brk, start_code, end_code,
    start_stack, arg_start, arg_end, env_start, env_end, brk_val;
    struct prctl_mm_map prctl_map;

    f = fopen("/proc/self/stat", "r");
    if (!f) {
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen(stat): '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
      return -1;
    }

    fd = fileno(f);
    if (fd < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "fileno(%p): '%m' (%d)\n", f, errno);
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    bytes_read = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1);
    if (bytes_read <= 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "read(): '%m' (%d)\n", errno);
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    buf[bytes_read] = '\0';

    /* Skip the first 25 fields, column 26-28 are start_code, end_code,
     * and start_stack */
    buf_ptr = strchr(buf, ' ');
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
          if (!buf_ptr) {
            fclose(f);
            return -1;
          }
      buf_ptr = strchr(buf_ptr + 1, ' ');
    }
    if (!buf_ptr) {
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    i = sscanf(buf_ptr, "%lu %lu %lu", &start_code, &end_code, &start_stack);
    if (i != 3) {
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    /* Skip the next 19 fields, column 45-51 are start_data to arg_end */
    for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
      if (!buf_ptr) {
        fclose(f);
        return -1;
      }
      buf_ptr = strchr(buf_ptr + 1, ' ');
    }

    if (!buf_ptr) {
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    i = sscanf(buf_ptr, "%lu %lu %lu %*u %*u %lu %lu", &start_data,
           &end_data, &start_brk, &env_start, &env_end);
    if (i != 5) {
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    /* Include the null byte here, because in the calculations below we
     * want to have room for it. */
    len = strlen(title) + 1;

    tmp_proctitle = realloc(proctitle, len);
    if (!tmp_proctitle) {
      fclose(f);
      return -1;
    }

    proctitle = tmp_proctitle;

    arg_start = (unsigned long)proctitle;
    arg_end = arg_start + len;

    brk_val = syscall(__NR_brk, 0);

    prctl_map = (struct prctl_mm_map){
        .start_code = start_code,
        .end_code = end_code,
        .start_stack = start_stack,
        .start_data = start_data,
        .end_data = end_data,
        .start_brk = start_brk,
        .brk = brk_val,
        .arg_start = arg_start,
        .arg_end = arg_end,
        .env_start = env_start,
        .env_end = env_end,
        .auxv = NULL,
        .auxv_size = 0,
        .exe_fd = -1,
    };

    ret = prctl(PR_SET_MM, PR_SET_MM_MAP, &prctl_map,
            sizeof(prctl_map), 0);
    if (ret == 0)
        (void)strncpy((char *)arg_start, title, len);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set cmdline\n");

    fclose(f);

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
    // show pid to find the right process
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid = %d\n", pid);

    if (argv[1]) {
      setproctitle(argv[1]);
      // ...
    }

      sleep(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run it:

```
$ gcc ptitle.c
$ ./a.out foo
pid = 3554
```

Then, cmdline is changed:

```
$ cat /proc/3554/cmdline
foo
```

But in this case, stat file still contains the executable name:

```
$ cat /proc/3554/stat  
3554 (a.out)[...]
```

And the same for status file:

```
$ cat /proc/3554/status
Name:   a.out
[...]
```

So you may also need to use the code of my preceding answer to change the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the PR_SET_NAME option of prctl(). The manual (man 2 prctl) says:

```
PR_SET_NAME (since Linux 2.6.9)
              Set the name of the calling thread, using the value in the location pointed to by (char *) arg2. The name can be up to 16 bytes long, including the terminating null byte.
(If the length of the  string, including the terminating null byte, exceeds 16 bytes, the string is silently truncated.)
```

Here is an example from your program (translated in C language as you tagged your post with C not C++ ;-) :

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prctl_routine(char *name)
{
    int ret = prctl(PR_SET_NAME, name);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("prctl");
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ...
    // show pid to find the right process
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid = %d\n", pid);

    if (argv[1]) {
      prctl_routine(argv[1]);
      sleep(1000);
      // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it:

```
$ gcc ptitle.c
```

I run it:

```
$ ./a.out foo
pid = 16812
```

And I check its name in /proc:

```
$ cat /proc/16812/status 
Name:   foo
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You considered setting name of the *calling thread*. But the goal is to hide a name of *executing file* from `/proc/pid/cmdline`. So It's supposed to look like that `cat /proc/16812/cmdline` -> `foo`

Comment: I added an answer inspired by the source code of LXC. This may fit your need.